# When multiple variables match, remove from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

So I currently have this, so if `$iDontWant` matches something in the array from `$data->Name`, it removes the whole line. Using the same method how could I do the same but with multiple `$iDontWant`? So say another `$iDontWant2`, and this also remove from the foreach? Every way I have tried seems to break things!

```
$iDontWant="bla"

foreach($datas as $data) {
    if($data->Name == $iDontWant) continue; 
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
}; ?>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `$iDontWant` as an array and use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$iDontWant = ["one", "two"];

foreach($datas as $data) {
    if(in_array($data->Name, $iDontWant)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to only loop the ones you want, just take the difference and loop that:

```
$iDontWant = ["one", "two"];

foreach(array_diff($datas, $iDontWant) as $data) {
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
}
```